# Passing state as props from Parent to Child in React-Router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, react-router

I have been using React-Router for the past couple of days and Iv'e been loving it! One problem that Iv'e been having is that I can't find the best way to pass state from my parent component to my child component. Iv'e been looking at several stack overflow and blog posts but I can't seem to find what Iv'e wanted. Here is a very over simplified example about what I'm looking for.

```
class App extends React.Component  {
  constuctor(props)  {
     super(props);
     this.state = {name:"helloworld", lastname:"world hello"};
  }

  render()  { // SOMETHING LIKE THIS WOULD BE PREFFERED
     if (this.props.children.name == "Home")  {
        {this.props.children myname={this.state.name}}
     }
     else if (this.props.children.name = "Account")  {
        {this.props.children anotherprop={this.state.lastname}}
     }
  }


}


class Home extends React.Component  {
  render()  {
    return (
      {this.props.myname}
    );
  }
}


class Account extends React.Component  {
  render()  {
  return (
    {this.props.lastname}
  );
  } 
}
//ROuting config - (Only the routes not the config)

<Route path="/" component={App}>
  <IndexRoute component={Home} />
  <Route path="account" component={account} />
</Route>
```

Obviously this is a very simplified version of what I am trying to accomplish but I hope you get the picture.

TLDR: How do I pass state from parent to child as props? Is there any way to do this via the parent component?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

All I did to fix this was use the cloneElement to create a clone and I could add my state props to that clone:

```
return React.cloneElement(
        this.props.children, 
        {appName: 'Foo'}
    );
}
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the whole solution? I don't understand where should I put this code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use context to pass data from parent to child component. Please refer example at https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

This perfectly works even if you use react-router, i am using it in my application.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that this is an _experimental_ feature, and may be *removed* by Facebook in the future:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

Answer (score 1):

**lufte** - if your original code looked like this:

```
render() {
  return(
    <div className="wrapper">
    {this.props.children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

then the revised code with data being passed to the component's children would be:

```
render() {
  var clonedChildren = React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {myProp: myValue});
  return(
    <div className="wrapper">
    {clonedChildren}
    </div>
  );
}
```